# Update object before add to the list

Tags: c#

I have some problem with update objects before I add them to list. For example when I have one object in `lst` and i get another one from `_context` with the same `id` and update `param`, object already added to the list also is updated. It looks like they have same address, but how?

Could anybody solve my problem?

```
List<Item> lst = new List<Item>();         
                foreach (Item currItemB in itemsB)
                {

                    Item newItem = new Item();
                    newItem = await _context.Item.Where(x => x.id == currItemB.id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                    newItem.param = currItemB.param;
      
                    lst.Add(newItem);

                }
```

Comment: What is the problem ?  what are you going to ahive? The same or not the same what is the difference for you? It should be the same.

Comment: I would like to divide them, because update ( newItem.param = currItemB.param;) is not the same for same id.

Comment: But you have to show the whole code, since I don't see any problem so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually creating a copy of the object. You are just using another pointer to the same address. In order to make the code run, you should create a copy from the "Item".
Create a clone function in the class "Item".
see [5 Ways to Clone An Object in C#](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-clone-an-object-in-c-d1374ec28efa)

Comment: Clone object solve my problem. Thanks.